# Creating a separated table

Tags: tables, programming

I'd like to be able to setup a bunch of things to put in a table after gathering them up before hand.  Something like the following where I keep a variable with the contents that will eventually be inserted into the document.  This technique seems to work fine until I start adding the table stuff like "&" and "\".

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mytable{}
\newcommand{\myitem}[2]{
  \edef\mytable{\mytable #1 & #2 \\ }
}

\begin{document}

\myitem{foo}{bar}
\myitem{foo}{bar}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \mytable
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'm getting this error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\\  ->\let \reserved@e 
                       \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv...
l.10 \myitem{foo}{bar}

?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `\edef` for this: many LaTeX commands do not survive it. Rather

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myitem}{%
  \g@addto@macro\mytable{#1 & #2 \\}%
}
\makeatother
```

There are several other techniques, if you don't want the addition to be global, which `\g@addto@macro` does.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\myitem}[2]{%
  \appto\mytable{#1 & #2 \\}%
}
```

will do the addition obeying the standard scoping rules.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, although using `\g@addto@macro` seems more reasonable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mytable{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myitem}[2]{%
  \protected@edef\mytable{\mytable #1 & #2 \\}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myitem{\textbf{foo}}{bar}
\myitem{one}{two}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \mytable
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\chardef` has nothing to do with this: you could just say `\let\\=\relax`.  Also note that `&` is already unexpandable.

Comment: `&` has no problem whatsoever in `\edef`. You're just making ``\\`` unexpandable during the `\edef`; but the problem doesn't vanish: try `\myitem{\textbf{a}}{b}`

Comment: @egreg - So the trick is to make everything unexpandable?

Comment: @JohnKormylo The trick is expanding nothing, except `\mytable`, but just one level.